# How to share global variables in jest test

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I would like to use variable `Shopresult` in jest test. this variable will be defined in `beforeAll` section.

```
describe("test",()=>{
    
    let Shopresult:Shop;

    beforeAll(async()=>{
        await getConnection(LocalOrmconfig).then(async()=>{
          const Shopresult = await getRepository(Shop).save(mockData)
        })
    })
    afterAll(async()=>{
        await getConnection(LocalOrmconfig).then(async()=>{
            await getRepository(PricingPattern)
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .delete()
            .where({shopId:Shopresult.shopId})
            .execute()
        })
    })
```

But above code invoked following error.

`'Shopresult' is declared but its value is never read.`

What is the root cause of this?
I declared them in let clause.

If someone has opinion,will you please let me know. thanks

Comment: you are creating a new variable in the beforeAll scope. Maybe remove the const?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line. it is not using the `Shopresult` defined outside but creating a new variable. Remove the `const` keyword

```
const Shopresult = await getRepository(Shop).save(mockData)
```